# Telerik combox find showing null in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" OnClientItemsRequesting="OnClientItemsRequesting" CheckBoxes="true" EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="true">   
                                        <Items>
                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="All" Value="All" />
                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Europe" Value="Europe" />
                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Middle East" Value="Middle East" />
                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Asia" Value="Asia" />
                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Africa" Value="Africa" />
                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="The Americas" Value="The Americas" />
                                        </Items>
                                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

For the above line of code I trying to get all selected check box values using javascrit. How can I achieve it. But before it I am getting null for the below line of code in my JS code

```
 $("#Button1").click(function () {
        debugger;
        var combo = $find("<%= DropDownList2.ClientID %>");

        return false;
    })
```

I am getting value of combo as null.

Comment: the following example might be useful http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/checkboxes/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Have you tried $get instead?  Or a JQuery selector?  I've had strange results sometimes using $find with telerik controls in events.